# array_unshift not working on a multidimensional array, PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to add an element to the beginning of a multidimensional array, but for some reason it's not recognizing the array I initialized as an array, even though I initialized it as an array. Please take a look:

> test.php

```
$array = array(); <---initialize an array;

array_unshift($array[0] , 'name'); <---add name to the array;
```

Here's the error message:

```
Warning: array_unshift() [function.array-unshift]: The first argument should be an array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that the first argument has to be array, not an array element.

So it's just:

```
array_unshift($array, 'name'); <---add name to the array;
```

*Just so you understand better, according to the [docs](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) `array_unshift` always adds to the beginning of an array, so you don't have to specify `[0]`*

Comment: I specifically wanted to add name to $array[0]. If I wanted to add name to a non-multi-dimensional array, I would've just done $array.

Comment: @frosty I get you. Then initialize your array to have `$array[0]`.  As in `$array = array(array());`. Your code would work fine if your `$array` is actually multidimensional.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a multidimensional array; it's an empty array.

A multi array contains two or more arrays.

```
$ar = array(1,2,3);
$arr = array(4,5,6);
$array = array ($ar, $arr);
array_unshift($array[0], 0);
```